# AnyChart intersection labels for Venn diagram in React

Tags: reactjs, anychart

In the documentation, under [Quick Start](https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Venn_Diagram#quick_start), there is a way to configure the labels of intersection

```
chart.intersections().labels().format("{%x}");
```

How to add the label in the intersection in the following React component?

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/anychart-venn-diagram-mqgy1k?file=/src/components/AnyCharts.jsx

Answer (score 0):

The anychart-react library is a great choice for quickly creating charts. However, its configuration is limited.

In your example, the label is visible by default.

[image]

If you want to achieve more advanced settings like [intersection formatting](https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Venn_Diagram#intersections), consider using vanilla JS modules that will be embedded in your React application.

Feel free to experiment with an example of [connecting your react app to anychart standalone modules](https://github.com/Bepely/anychart_react).